# Why isn't getItemView in my custom ParseQueryAdapter being called?

Tags: android, parse-platform

In my debugger, my custom query is created without crashing.  However, getItemView is never called and I don't know why:

```
public class CustAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter {

public CustAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<MyData>() {

        public ParseQuery create() {
                ParseQuery custQuery = new ParseQuery("MyData");

                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

                String selectedOption = MainActivity.getSelectedOption();

                custQuery.whereEqualTo("option", 
                                       selectedOption).whereExists("bookTitle");

                questionsQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt");

                return custQuery;
        } // end create()
    }); // end anon inner class and end super call
}


public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView titleTV;
    TextView detailsTV;
}


@Override
public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.book_item, null);
        super.getItemView(object, v, parent);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.titleTV = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.bTitle);
        holder.detailsTV = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.bDetails);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();

    holder.titleTV.setText(object.getString("bookTitle"));
    holder.detailsTV.setText(object.getString("bookDetails"));
    return v;
}
}
```

In my fragment I do: CustAdapter adapter = new CustAdapter(getActivity()); lv.setAdapter(adapter).

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct, the problem was setting the listview to invisible in the xml.  Making it visible in the controller shows the cloud results.  Amazingly android studio still did not hit the breakpoint set at the if statement in getItemView!